# Can't perform Social Sign in with google in playwright as google prevents it. Is there a way around using Playwright? I'm using Chromium

Tags: jestjs, e2e-testing, webautomation, playwright

In the following code I'm trying to login in with sign in with google button but after entering
email and clicking next it takes me to error screen, which I have attached it as picture

```
it('Sign Up With Google ', async() => {
    await page.waitForSelector(signUpWithGoogle, { state: 'visible' });
    await page.click(signUpWithGoogle);
    await page.click(signUpWithGoogle);
    const [popup] = await Promise.all([
       page.waitForEvent('popup'),
       page.click(signUpWithGoogle),
       page.click(signUpWithGoogle)
    ])
    await popup.fill('//input[@type="email"]', googleEmail);
    await popup.click('//span[text()="Next"]');
    await popup.waitForTimeout(10000);
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
}, timeforSigninWithGoogle)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Apparently those google accounts which have 2F authentication enabled will not be signed in and will give you above error in chromium but those accounts which doesn't have 2F authentication will worked on both webkit and chromium

Comment: See the same error even when 2FA authentication is turned off in google account. Not sure if there are any policy changes on google post this answer.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for 2FA-enabled google accounts? Thank you.